# How to get the title of the metadata which is placed in directories in resources folder

Tags: iphone

i am new to iphone programming. i want to get the title of mp3 file which is located in directory of Resourse folder

Resourse Folder Structure is following

Resourse

raj(directory)---->1.mp3
              ---->2.mp3

Here i know to get the path of the file if i get path it shows like this

/Users/Chary/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/B02404E5-52DC-49B6-8DBB-C9946E4331AF/BiblePlayer.app/raj/1.mp3

I have a picker view in that i have to show only title like as "1","2" for 1.mp3 and 2.mp3
but how can get like this it will show the entire path

so,if any body know this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
NSString * mp3FilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                    pathForResource:@"1"
                                             ofType:@"mp3"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
//Provide another path if you have folder in your directory
NSArray *arrDirVideos = [fileManager  contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
```

It will give all files for path you provided in array like { 1.mp3,2.mp3,..} So now u can elimate .mp3 from each item of array